# Need Windows 7 cmd line equivalent of the command " ssh-keygen -t rsa -C <youremail@domanname.com>

Tags: ssh

I am reading Michael Hartl's "Ruby On Rails 3 Tutorial" and have come to the point where I am pushing my first_app to Github. When I first tried this I got the error "Permission denied: (publickey). I thought the problem was I did not have a SSH keypair for Github. So in following their advice for generation a new keypair from the URL https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys
I typed in 
    ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your_email@youremail.com"
To which I received the error 
   "ssh-keygen is not recognized as an external or internal command, operable program, or batch file."

I am using Windows 7 OS. So I think my problem is that this command line entry is for Mac or Linux based command lines. Can someone please tell me the Windows 7 OS equivalent of this entry, so that I can create a new SSH keypair and continue on with the tutorial?

Comment: possible duplicate of ['ssh-keygen' is not recognized as an internal or external command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11771378/ssh-keygen-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Answer (score 3):

Flip the url to windows-specific:
https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys#platform-windows
and note that they say to "Open the GIT bash", not the windows CMD.

Comment: This alone is not an answer and installing bash won't help the OP to have OpenSSH.

Answer (score 2):

ssh-keygen is part of Openssh package which you can install separately (Look for CopSSH for Windows, which is a Windows port of OpenSSH).

Comment: I had to get CopSSH because OpenSSH 1.01e didn't include it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The first step is installing open-ssh, one way is indeed by installing [Git for Windows](http://git-scm.com/download/win). During the installation choose the third option of being able to use the "unix" tools from the command line.

I have a small wrapper utility that loads the agent to memory in [github](http://erezak.github.io/ssh-agent-wrapper-win) (#selfplug) and your identities, allowing an easy use from the command line.