# Where to put database if planning on marketing and distrubiting app

Tags: android

I am planning on marketing my app in Google Play. In order to get into my app the user has to login/register. My current database for the login and registration is on localhost and is connected via an API. If I am planning on distrubting, should I put my database online? Or what are the different options on where to put my database?

Answer (score 0):

You should look into renting a [Virtual Private Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_server). A virtual server that you pay a monthly fee for, for certain resources.

This box will be your server. You can install Apache and send HTTP requests for response. You can install MySQL and have a full on database.

Answer (score 0):

If they need an account on a server somewhere, yes, you'll need something to handle that. A website supplying a webservice for your app to use, something of that sort.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out Heroku - https://www.heroku.com/

If it's a small app, you could use the free option.

Comment: Thanks. Real quick question..I got the same error as [this guy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15018591/could-not-generate-ssh-public-key-for-heroku-in-windows-7) and I noticed one guy's answer saying to add ssh-keygen.exe to my system path. I'm lost on how to do that