# Google Compute Engine SSH

Tags: google-compute-engine

I just create new instance and now wan to remote my google compute engine. And when i do this, i have an error like this.

```
D:\>gcutil --service_version="service_version_name" --project="project_name" ssh--  zone="zone_name" "instance_name"
WARNING: You don't have an ssh key for Google Compute Engine. Creating one now..
.
WARNING: Could not generate compute ssh key: There was a problem running ssh-key
gen: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Why it ask file specified? How to fix the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have `ssh-keygen` installed on your system, so `gcutil` is unable to generate an SSH keypair.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11771907/873145) for installation instructions (note that this pulls in git too, but that's a way to get `ssh-keygen` on Windows).

---

Note on why `gcutil` is trying to generate an SSH keypair:

You need an SSH keypair to be able to connect to an instance. Launching an instance without a keypair would most likely make it unusable, so the `gcutil` agent is attempting to generate a new keypair for you.

This is done using the `ssh-keygen` utility.

Answer (score 0):

`gcutil` is not very easy to use at Windows.
I suggest using puttygen and putty, please follow [instructions from Google](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/console).

Answer (score 0):

It will succeed when run from `cygwin`. I suggest this is because ssh-keygen is trying to find  `/`.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was fixed last week. Please reinstall your Cloud SDK from https://developers.google.com/cloud/sdk/

Please note that Cygwin is not required any more (we have a native Windows installer)

Answer (score 0):

try with

gcloud compute ssh "instanse"

on windows if you are auth previusly, open a putty windows automatically

Answer (score 0):

The trick here is to use the -C (comment) parameter to specify your GCE userid. It looks like Google introduced this change earlier this year.

If the Google user who owns the GCE instance is myname@gmail.com (which you will use as your login userid), then generate the key pair with (for example)

```
ssh-keygen -b521 -t ecdsa -C myname -f mykeypair
```

When you paste mykeypair.pub into the instance's public key list, you should see "myname" appear as the userid of the key.

Setting this up will let you use ssh, scp, etc from your command line.