# Why can the Git Shell use SSH with an HTTP remote origin URL?

Tags: powershell, github, ssh, github-for-windows, git-shell

I have read [Configuring Git over SSH to login once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595848/configuring-git-over-ssh). Muein Muzamil's answer says that to use SSH, we must configure as follows:

`remote.origin.url=git@github.com:your_username/your_project.git`

Which is to say, that in a normal Windows PowerShell, SSH does not work with HTTPS.

GitHub for Windows comes with the Git Shell. It's a souped-up PowerShell with some fancy features, including the ability to use SSH with HTTP. I know this because I just ran `git push` without needing to authenticate, and then ran `git config -l` to see that I am using HTTPS as the remote origin url.

Why does a normal Windows PowerShell require the git@github.com protocol whereas a Git Shell does not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Windows PowerShell, SSH does not work with HTTPS

That doesn't make sense: you are using ssh or you are using https (http with ssl). One "does not work with" the other.

[G4W (GitHub for Windows)](https://windows.github.com/) has your GitHub account credentials, so it can use an https url.

A regular Git shell from [msysgit/Git for Windows](http://msysgit.github.io/) can use https or ssh, BUT for ssh, you need to make sure that:

- the environment variable `%HOME%` is defined (which [`git-cmd.bat`](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/blob/master/git-cmd.bat) or [git-bash.vbs](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/blob/master/share/WinGit/Git%20Bash.vbs) do for you),
- your `id_rsa(.pub)` private/public [ssh keys are in it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26232845/6309),
- your `id_rsa.pub` public key is [published in your GitHub account](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/#step-3-add-your-ssh-key-to-github).

Comment: "G4W... has your GitHub account credentails, so it can use ... HTTPS." That answers my question.

Comment: A follow up question (that might belong in its own SO question): *Why does GitHub for Windows (G4W) create an SSH key?* After installation, there is an `~\.ssh\github_rsa` key and its `.pub`. Does G4W ever use this or does it instead always use HTTPS? My own sense is that GFW uses the SSH key when it's communicating over the `git@github.com` protocol and using the username and password otherwise, and that we can manually control this using `git remote set-url origin <someUrl>` command.

Comment: What you are thinking is probably right but `git@github.com` is not an protocol, ssh is. Git creates the ssh key to authenticate over ssh. After authenticating you can push/pull.

Comment: @ShaunLuttin that is a good separate question. I will look it up.

Comment: @VonC I look forward to your answer.

Comment: @ShaunLuttin I would need a new question, for me to post a new answer ;)