# While adding an ssh-key in gitlab using git bash, I am getting the error: "Saving key 'keyname' failed: Permission Denied". What shall I do?

Tags: git, cmd, gitlab, git-bash, ssh-keygen

While adding an **ssh-key** in gitlab using **git bash**, I am getting the **error**:

> "Saving key 'keyname' failed: Permission Denied"

. What shall I do?

This is the input-

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "name@email.com"
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/c/Users/UserName/.ssh/id_rsa): fileName
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Saving key "fileName" failed: Permission denied
```

PS- Following things I have already tried-

1. Setting the environment variable
2. I have used **cmd** for inserting the same command, but was getting the following error- "**ssh-keygen** is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"
3. Changing the current directory to

> C:\Program Files\Git\bin

This is the path that I have set *(as suggested from another SO question)*-

> C:\Program Files\Git\bin\ssh-keygen.exe

This was the [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11771378/ssh-keygen-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command) that I referred. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have used cmd for inserting the same command,

That is a valid approach

> but was getting the following error- "ssh-keygen is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"

Simply add to your `%PATH%` `<path\to\git>\usr\bin`.
And don't use the msi setup, simply unzip the [latest release](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) anywhere you want:
[`PortableGit-2.9.0-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.9.0.windows.1/PortableGit-2.9.0-64-bit.7z.exe) (self-extracting archive).

For instance:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\git\PortableGit-2.9.0-64-bit.7z.exe\usr\bin
```

Make sure you are in `%USERPPROFILE%`: `ssh-keygen` will generate those keys in  `%USERPPROFILE%\.ssh`.

The [OP Trivedi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6359835/trivedi) confirms it is working with:

> I didn't give a filename; i.e. just pressed 'enter' when asked for filename and passphrase!

That is the easiest way: default `id_rsa(.pub)` named keys, with no passphrase.

Comment: Well, it's a bit funny and weird, but I didn't give a filename; i.e. just pressed 'enter' when asked for filename and passphrase!

Comment: @Trivedi I have edited the answer to include your comment and explain what not entering a filename and password means.

Comment: @Trivedi That is the idea indeed :)