# Command not found: ssh OpenSSH not found on your computer

Tags: windows, ssh, ionic3, openssh

I'm trying to set up Ionic pro. But it gives an error.Any help?

I have installed  `Git Bash`.But still, it shows above error. Why?

> May we proceed? Yes
>
> > ionic ssh generate C:\Users\lokuge.ssh\ionic\4460 [ERROR] Command not found: ssh [WARN] OpenSSH not found on your computer. [INFO] You
> >     will be prompted to provide a passphrase, which is used to protect
> >     your private key should you lose it. (If
> >            someone has your private key, they can impersonate you!) Passphrases are recommended, but not required. 'ssh-keygen' is not
> >     recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or
> >     batch file. [ERROR] Command not found: ssh-keygen

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Simple: install SSH

Since you seem to be on Windows, I suggest getting [Git Bash](https://git-scm.com/download/win). That ships with OpenSSH. Oh, and Git, obviously.

Edit, because the solution is actually in the comments:
You have to run whatever command is causing the error in Visual Studio **from within the actual Bash shipped with Git Bash**. Simply installing Git Bash but running the command from within VS does *not* work, as VS assumedly uses a different terminal emulator.

Comment: I installed git bash. Still, it shows when I run `ionic link`. Why?

Comment: What is the output of `ssh-keygen --help`?

Comment: This `'ssh-keygen' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`. I'm running this within `vs code`.

Comment: Try running it from the actual Git Bash terminal. Also check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11771378/ssh-keygen-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command

Comment: Then it shows the content. But within `VS code` not working. Why?

Comment: My guess, without ever having touched VS code, is that it isn't loading the Bash that ships with Git Bash, but instead either uses Windows' `cmd`, or some custom terminal-like implementation. Ionic, however, expects a Mac/Unix system, as it is calling `ssh-keygen`. If your `%PATH%` is setup correctly, you might be able to call `ssh-keygen.exe` from a plain `cmd`... Wrapping things up: always use Git Bash for your setup-work.

Comment: Thanks for the support. I did it through Git bash :)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, I have downloaded and configure ssh via cygwin I'm i going to use Cygwin to run ionic pro instead of cmd, because while i run ionic pro on cmd i have an error of : ionic ssh setup
[WARN] OpenSSH not found on your computer.
[ERROR] Command not found: ssh